# Expected Value of Nonnegative Identically Distributed Random Variables

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, expected-value

Let $X_1, X_2 \geq 0$ be two non-negative identically distributed random variables. I wonder if the following equation holds.

$$
\mathbb{E}[X_1X_2] = \mathbb{E}[Y^2]
$$
where $Y$ is a random variable having the common distribution of $\{X_1, X_2\}$.

**My attempt:** We know that, in general, $\mathbb{E}[X_1X_2] \neq \mathbb{E}[X_1^2]$ and/or $\mathbb{E}[X_1X_2] \neq \mathbb{E}[X_2^2]$. One can take $X_1 \in \{0,1\}$ with probability $1/2$ and take $X_2 := -X_1$. However, the nonnegativity excludes this case.

Also, if we look at
$$
\mathbb{E}[Y^2] = \int y^2\, dF_{Y} = \int y^2 \, dF_{X_1,X_2}
$$
where the last equality hold since $Y$ has the common joint distribution of $\{X_1,X_2\}$. But I get stuck to see if this is equal to $
\mathbb{E}[X_1X_2] = \int x_1x_2 \,dF_{X_1,X_2}$. Any comment is appreciated.

Comment: What if $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent?

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to find such examples. If $EX_1X_2=EX_1^{2} (=EX_2^{2})$ then $E(X_1-X_2)^{2}=EX_1^{2}+EX_2^{2}-2EX_1X_2=0$ so $X_1=X_2$ a.s..  Can you come up with two non-negative r.v.'s with the same distribution (say $exp(1)$)  which are not a.s. equal?